# Date, status monitoring

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a script that monitors the dates entered in the 'Date of Installation' and 'Next Service Date' columns. If the time period between the 'Date of Installation' and 'Next Service Date' is exactly 4 months, for instance, if the 'Date of Installation' is July 6, 2023, and the 'Next Service Date' is October 20, 2023, indicating a 4-month gap, I want the 'Status' column cell to change to red. This red cell color will serve as an alert to the project manager, prompting them to inform their team. Once the alert is acknowledged, and a date is filled in another column called 'Date of Service' column, the 'Status' cell should return to its original white color. Also i want the notification send and email in google sheet. I have tried but i keep on having issues on chnaging the colors in the status column and acknowleding the date of seervice column

```
function sendEmailNotifications() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var today = new Date();

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var installationDate = new Date(data[i][3]);
    var nextServiceDate = new Date(data[i][4]);
    var dateOfService = new Date(data[i][5]);

    var differenceInMonths = (nextServiceDate - installationDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30.44);

    if (differenceInMonths >= 4 && today >= nextServiceDate) {
      var clientName = data[i][0];
      var location = data[i][1];
      var systemInstalled = data[i][2];
      
      var message = "Greetings,\n\nIt's time for the next service for " + clientName + " at " + location + ". The system installed is " + systemInstalled + ".\n\nRegards,\nBenazir Mirza,\nProject Manager";
      
      // Replace 'your_email@example.com' with your email address.
      var recipient = 'chibonitimothy@gmail.com';
      var subject = 'Service Due Notification';
      
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, message);

      // Change 'Status' cell to red
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 7).setValue("Red");
    } else if (differenceInMonths < 4 && dateOfService !== "") {
      // Date of Service updated, stop sending notifications and change 'Status' cell to white
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 7).setValue("White");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is always good to include a spreadsheet with dummy data, which makes the problem you are facing more clear to people looking into it. It should show your attempts and your expected outcomes

Comment: @Nabnub if you follow that link the op will know your email address

Comment: @Cooper Thanks. You mean op could use something like `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` ? or they are other methods as well ?

Comment: No they'll just get a link they can hover over and see your email and add it to their contacts with no thinking whatsoever.  It's a great idea if you like spam.

Comment: Client Name Location System Installed Date of Installation Next Service Date Date of Service Status Comment
John Phiri Lusaka West Alarm 6/25/2023 10/26/2023   
Alice Mable Chalala Camera 10/27/2023 10/26/2023   
Peter Kabwe Kalundu Siren 5/20/2023 10/26/2023   
John Zulu Kangwa Guard 6/18/2023 10/26/2023